# React jquery .toggleClass() does only work after compiler reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I´m trying to build this *sideboard* for my react application:
https://codepen.io/illnino/pen/nwPBrQ . Anyways, I ran into a problem and I´m not able to solve this on my own.

### So what is my exact problem ?

This code does NOT work if I try to hover on the sideboard icon as it should. After refreshing the page *manually*, it doesnt work either. But I noticed, if my **react compiler reloads this application** (after any change in my file) and I DON'T refresh the page manually, it works.

So `.toggleClass()` does only work, after my compiler *reloads* the code. After reloading the page on my own, it doesnt work again.

### My Code

My css code is exact the *same* as on codepen. Of course the javascript and the html code are in the **same** file. The html code is also the same, so I´ll only give you my JS code (In fact I´m using *typescript*, but that shouldn't matter):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    $(".gn-icon-menu").hover(function () {
        let e = $(".gn-menu-wrapper")
        e.toggleClass("gn-open-part")
      });
  
      $(".gn-menu-wrapper").hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("gn-open-all")
      });
  }, []);
```

### What have I tried ?

I really dont know, what to try. I´ll hope somebody maybe has a clue, what the error could be...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery manipulates the DOM, React schedules updates to its own Virtual DOM. You should try to avoid using both. They don't get along with one another. If you write all the styles in a css sheet and then use those, you can achieve the same results.

```
.gn-menu-wrapper {
    /* Base Styles */
}
.gn-menu-wrapper:hover {
    /* Hover Styles here */
}
```

Also double check your style sheets are SCSS and not CSS. In this codepen example they are using the format: (&) this will not work in CSS.

```
&::placeholder{
    color: $f-c;
}
```